# How to count number of element in array data in Firestore?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am studying Firestore with React.
After I added the array data into the firestore, I am trying to count the certain element in array of data in the document.
Like the picture I attached, there are several documents includes array data.
I want to count the number of CS 34800 in class array from all documents.
What is the best way to get it?
Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnEXv.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no counting or aggregating operations on Firebase, so that way you have it now, you will have to query for all the documents that match your criteria, then count the number of documents in your result set.

You can use an ["array_contains" operator](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) to get all the documents where an array contains some value.

```
collectionRef.where("class", "array-contains", "CS 34800").get()
.then(querySnapshot => {
    const count = querySnapshot.size
});
```

If you need to get a count without making a query for documents, you'll have to maintain that yourself for every string that you could possibly need to count, which is an entirely different problem.

Comment: great! how can i handle when there is no such a document on your code?
i mean, if there is no then console.log("no docs") something like that..

Comment: Then your querySnapshot will have a size of 0.  Check for that.

Comment: Is possible recover all fields  of the array and return the size of ths same array?

Comment: Example: You have an array with 10 elements, but you do not know that array have 10 elements and you need to know. So, you recover all elements from the array and you'll to increment for each element that was recovered.

Comment: if u wanna add something like a fallback like console.log("something went wrong!") then add a CATCH after the THEN function